# Ошибка при использовании простой функции

Tags: c

У меня есть функция, которая должна вернуть char из конкретной "ячейки" в непрерывном блоке выделенной памяти.

```
static char getModOfBlock(void * block){
    return *((char*)(block-11));
}

if(!(getModOfBlock(*ptr_from_allocated) == 'A' || getModOfBlock(*ptr_from_allocated) == 'G' (userIsInTrust(memcache->users, user, username)) || (!strcmp(user, username)))){
        return MEMCACHE_PERMISSION_DENIED;
 }
```

Я получаю следюущую ошибку, абсолютно не понимая почему. Кто-то видит какие-либо основания ? Да, типом `ptr` является `void**`

```
called object is not a function or function pointer
```

Answer (score 6):

Очевидно, что данное `if`-предложение синтаксически некорректно.

```
if(!(getModOfBlock(*ptr_from_allocated) == 'A' || 
     getModOfBlock(*ptr_from_allocated) == 'G' 
    (userIsInTrust(memcache->users, user, username)) ||
    (!strcmp(user, username))))
{
    return MEMCACHE_PERMISSION_DENIED;
}
```

Что означает данная часть условия

```
     getModOfBlock(*ptr_from_allocated) == 'G' 
    (userIsInTrust(memcache->users, user, username)) ||
    (!strcmp(user, username))))
```

неясно.

Также данное `return` предложение

```
return *((char*)(block-11));
```

также некорректное, так как указатель `block` имеет тип `void *`,

```
static char getModOfBlock(void * block){
                          ^^^^^^
```

а потому арифметика указателей `block-11` неприменима для этого типа указателей, так как тип `void` - это неполный тип. Его размер неизвестен.

Может быть вы имели в виду

```
return *( (char*)block - 11 );
```

Правда использование отрицательного смещения вызывает вопросы к функции.

Comment: Точно пропустил ||

Comment: Арифметика с `void*` работает в сях, но не в плюсах. У ТС как раз сишечка в тегах.

Comment: @alexolut Я не понимаю значение слов "работает". Это некорректный код и в C , и в C++.

Comment: `c99` 6.2.5/16 `A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.` и далее `The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.`

Comment: Хотя, вероятно, Вы правы и работоспособность определяется расширениями языка от конкретных реализаций. [Вопрос на английском SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c)

Comment: @alexolut В этом цитате из стандарта ничего не говорится про то, можно ли использовать тип void * в арифметике указателей. Если же посмотреть описание оператора -, то там написано, что "— the left operand is a pointer to a complete object type and the right operand has integer type.," То есть говорится про завершенный тип.

Comment: Ну, кто как, а gcc арифметику с void \* ест (воспринимет как char \*)

Comment: @avp Это не соответствует стандарту языка, а потому делает вашу программу зависящей от конкретного компилятора. То есть делает вашу программу, не удовлетворяющую стандарту языка C.

Comment: Тем хуже для стандартов.